# URL Rewrite in classic asp from html page to html

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am working on a site and I have to do url rewriting there. I have page www.mywebsite/Index.html. When user types this url in browser and hit enter. This will load content of page www.mywebsite/Index.asp but url should be rewritten as www.mywebsite/AllInfo.html. I have full access on IIS 7.5. Please guide how can i do that in IIS or through any other way. If through IIS what pattern should i use ? I searched from internet tried to use pattern like this 
   `^Index/([_0-9a-z-]+)`
and Rewrite Url action as `AllInfo.html` but in vain. Please guide

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, I have tried my self but couldn't find solution. Any help there ?

Comment: Can you show us anything that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ASP.NET installed on the server, you can use the [IIS URL Rewrite extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to re-write URLs for any file type. You will need to upload a properly configured `web.config` file to the server. There are a few questions and answers here that cover some of the basics as well as some tutorials on the extension's page.